# PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column courts.user_id does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rspec

This is the error I receive when I run a test for [this](https://github.com/IvanDerlich/court-reservation/blob/fe3d561d3adef404408d0cfa7d2742a8d48bb0ec/spec/models/user_spec.rb) file.

The error is in line 83 when I attempt to remove the user from the database using the 'destroy' method.

[This](https://github.com/IvanDerlich/court-reservation/tree/fe3d561d3adef404408d0cfa7d2742a8d48bb0ec) is the repo in question frozen in time.

The error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column courts.user_id does not exist
       LINE 1: SELECT "courts".* FROM "courts" WHERE "courts"."user_id" = $...
```

[image]

I'm trying to connect the table users with the table court this way:

- User is the administrator of many courts
- A court can have only one administrator

As you can see, 'Court' has a foreign key linked to 'users', but called 'administrator'.

I want 'administrator' to be the alias of a user because in the future User and Court might have more relationships: 'owner' for example.

I can see that active record is building this query:

```
SELECT "courts".* FROM "courts" WHERE "courts"."user_id" = $...
```

Maybe this can be solved if Active Record build a query this way

```
SELECT "courts".* FROM "courts" WHERE "courts"."administrator_id" = $...
```

But I don't know how to do it and if that would be prudent.

Maybe there is another way to do this. Something tidier, I feel I'm not doing the association properly.

What do you recommend?

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save :format_input
    # extend Devise::Models
    # Include default devise modules        .
    devise  :database_authenticatable,                
            # :validatable,
            # :recoverable,
            # :rememberable,
            # :trackable,             
            # :confirmable,
            # :omniauthable,
            :registerable
    
    # note that this include statement comes AFTER the devise block above
    include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
    validates :first_name, presence: true, length: { in: 1..20 }
    validates :last_name, presence: true, length: { in: 1..20 }
    validates :email, uniqueness: true
    validates_format_of :email, with: /@/
    validates :password, presence: true, length: { in: 8..20 }, :on => :create

    has_many :courts, dependent: :destroy
    
    private

    def format_input
            self.first_name = first_name.downcase.titleize
            self.last_name = last_name.downcase.titleize
            self.email = email.downcase
    end
end
```

models/court.rb

```
class Court < ApplicationRecord 

  belongs_to :administrator, :class_name => :user
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { in: 1..20 }
  validates :address, presence: true, length: { in: 1..50 }
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { in: 1..100 }
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { in: 1..100 }

end
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code (your models) to the question itself. Simply linking to your github repo or other external sources is not accepted by the community as you shouldn't expect people willing to spend time answering your question to have to dig around and it also contributes to link rot which makes questions worthless over time. https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've put the relevant code in the question in order to make this question age well

Comment: To make it easy for other people to read in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is on this line.

```
has_many :courts, dependent: :destroy
```

By default, ActiveRecord assumes the foreign key is named `<lowercased_parent_class_name>_id`. In this case, when you delete a user, ActiveRecord is trying to delete the associated courts using the `user_id` foreign key which doesn't exist. Pass the `foreign_key` option to the `has_many` call.

```
has_many :courts, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: :administrator_id
```

From the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many):

> `:foreign_key`
>
> Specify the foreign key used for the association. By default this is guessed to be the name of this class in lower-case and `_id` suffixed. So a Person class that makes a `has_many` association will use `person_id` as the default `:foreign_key`.

There's another issue. You should pass the uppercased class name as a string in the `belongs_to` call in the `Court` model.

```
belongs_to :administrator, class_name: 'User'
```

---

This is unrelated to the question but you might want to check if it is okay to delete a court when the user record is deleted.

Comment: Thanks, bro. This was the solution.